# git diff --name-only shows unchanged files

Tags: git, git-diff

### Edit: It doesn't, I explained below what made me think so.

I am working on a feature branch and the output of the command `git diff develop --name-only` shows a large list of files:

```
...

path/to/some/unchangedFile.cpp

...
```

and the command `git diff develop -- path/to/some/unchangedFile.cpp` shows no output and the files are identical in both commits.

What could cause such issue?

Comment: Have you checked the file mode?

Comment: I did now and it made me realize the path is relative to the repository's root and not to the working directory as I expected mistakenly. I'll remove the question in a minute. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

So the problem for me was that:

**a. The printed paths were relative to the repository's root and are not absolute or relative to the working directory.** I personally think it is a bad implementation because most of the time when I use --name-only I will want to perform a task on the files that were changed and I shouldn't need to "trim" the path myself

**b. git-diff doesn't print anything when the file argument doesn't exist on both commits.** That is counter intuitive in my opinion. When no output is shown I assume the file exists and is identical in both commits. I think a warning message is appropriate in this case.

Comment: StackOverflow isn't the right place to submit issues. If you think that the current behaviour of git is bad, [contact the community](https://git-scm.com/community). But at this point, you're answer (and question) is opinion based.

Comment: I agree with you but it won't let me remove the question after it was answered. Also, even if I could delete it, SO threats deleting questions with a "question ban" and I couldn't know beforehand that it was opinion based.

Comment: git-diff supports relative paths at least since v2.5.2. To print out paths relative to current working directory: "git diff --relative --name-only".

Answer (score 0):

You can list the (tracked) files changed in your feature branch since it was created like so  :

```
$ git --no-pager diff --name-only FETCH_HEAD $(git merge-base FETCH_HEAD develop)
```

`$(git merge-base FETCH_HEAD develop)` returns the last commit on develop before creating the current branch. Then `diff` compare the current head to this commit.

You can also see files changed since the last commit

```
$ git --no-pager diff --name-only FETCH_HEAD~1
```